# Closed form of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-x \tanh(x))}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I want to approximate the integral of a function over the whole real line very accurately. The integrand should be analytic in a strip but also have exponential decay. A prototypical example is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-x \tanh(x))}{1+x^2},$$ however, I don't know the exact value of this integral and Wolframalpha only yields accuracy to 6 digits (1.49774). Therefore I can't compare my approximation properly.

Is there any closed form of this integral or if not, what would be another good example of an analytic (in a strip) function with exponential decay which has a closed form?

Comment: Most integrals do not have closed forms. The highly complicated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm will be able to compute whether the antiderivative is expressible without special functions.

Comment: Executing `intnum(x=[-oo,1],[+oo,1],exp(-x*tanh(x))/(1+x^2))` in [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) yields $$1.49774386207663464450959894138999087216720034873851539897661449996652658714912\cdots$$